# how to center the image in a div when using transform scale

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making some functions in JavaScript for zoom in and zoom out with transform scale. The functions work very well.The problem is that the zoomed image move down on zoom out and up on zoom in. I want to keep it to the center of the div.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9M7gV/3/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div  class="skew"><img id="blah" align="middle" style="margin:0 auto 0 auto;"src="http://3rdbillion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/a24cc9de0c523a5bf7680e18af1952853.jpg"/></div>

<div id="zoom">
    <button type="button" value="zoom in" id="in" onclick="zoomin()" style=" width:80px;height: 25px;">Zoom In</button><br>
    <button type="button" value="zoom out" onclick="zoomout()" id="out"style="height: 25px;" >Zoom Out</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.skew {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 120px;
    width: 360px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function zoomin()
{
    document.getElementById('blah').style.transform = "scale(2,2)";
    document.getElementById('blah').style.webkitTransform = "scale(2,2) ";
    document.getElementById('blah').style.msTransform = "scale(2,2)";
}   


function zoomout()
{
    document.getElementById('blah').style.transform = "scale(0.5,0.5) ";
    document.getElementById('blah').style.webkitTransform = "scale(0.5,0.5)";
    document.getElementById('blah').style.msTransform = "scale(0.5,0.5)";
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code in a fiddle?

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9M7gV/3/ for some reason it doesn't work but i think it will help you understand what is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9M7gV/4/).

HTML

```
<div  class="skew">
    <img id="blah" src="http://3rdbillion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/a24cc9de0c523a5bf7680e18af1952853.jpg"/>
</div>
<br />
<button type="button" value='' id="in">Zoom In</button>
<br />
<button type="button" value="" id="out">Zoom Out</button>
```

CSS

```
.skew {
  height: 120px;
  width: 360px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    height: 120px;
    width: 360px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

JS

```
$('#in').on('click', function(){
  $('#blah').css("transform", "scale(2, 2)");
                                });

$('#out').on('click', function(){
  $('#blah').css("transform", "scale(0.5, 0.5)");
});
```